# php compare two strings and create one based on part of the string

Tags: php, oracle

I have two php strings that comes from ORACLE:

```
array (size=4)
 0 => string '30 Jan 2014| 09:00-10:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
 1 => string '30 Jan 2014| 10:00-11:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
 2 => string '06 Feb 2014| 09:00-10:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
 3 => string '06 Feb 2014| 10:00-11:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
```

..and I'm looking for a way to get this:

```
array (size=4)
 0 => string '30 Jan 2014 | 09:00-11:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
 1 => string '06 Jan 2014 | 09:00-11:00 | Workshop' (length=61)
```

Basically to combine two same-date records into one with combined time... I need to do this while getting all record in a

> foreach($result as $row){}

loop..
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I have tried to use substr() but i can't get my head round of "how to compare date with the previous one..

Comment: Try to use explode(' | ') on each line.

Comment: another option was explode, but again I have to compare the date with the one before.. and with thye next one

Comment: It's like: `code`foreach($result as $row){ if(explode("|", $sring) == ?`code`... and I'm stuck

Comment: You can save your résult in a temporary array keyed by date and 'Workshop'

Comment: Your approach **with PHP** seems to be inefficient. You should do  it **with SQL**.

Comment: I'm new to oracle so this would be an advanced function for me.. I have no idea how it may look like.. That's why i'm trying to use PHP instead.. But it doesn't seem to work either...))

Comment: Are these results always sorted by time ascending?

Comment: Yeap.. Sort by starttime desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to keep track of the previous date in a variable and then you can compare it on your next loop iteration. After doing your comparison you update it so it contains the current value. The next iteration then can do the same comparison and variable assignment.

Basic idea:

```
$current_date = '';
foreach($result as $row){
    // get date here
    $date = 'get date from your string here';

    // Do your check
    if ($current_date === $date) {
        // do something
    }

     // save the date for the next iteration
    $current_date = $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be able to do this in your database query, using something like GROUPING. I am not familiar enough with Oracle to exactly tell you how, but i'm sure enough people around here are.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: It totally should, unfortunately i don't have enough rep points for that.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone will look at this..:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
  $date = show_date($row->getField('STARTTIME'));
if($current_date === $date)
 {
   $EndTime = convert_time($row->getField('ENDTIME'));
 }
else 
 {
   $StartTime  = convert_time($row->getField('STARTTIME'));
   $EndTime = '';
     }
$current_date = $date;
}
```

Sorted thanks to John